# Grails set mapping table of 3 classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am new to grails. I have 3 classes as follws

```
class Cycle 
{
    int year
    int quarter
}

class User
{
    String username, password           
}           

class Role
{
    String roleName 
}
```

The User and Role tables are independent and they stores details of all employees and Available roles respectively.
An employee can have many roles in each cycle. so i want a mapping table like

[image]

to find what all roles belongs to an employee in a particular cycle.
How do i set proper relation between these classes to solve this  scenario so that if i have a cyle and a user , i can find out what all roles the user has in that cycle 
also if i have a user i can find which all cycles he involved an his roles in each of these cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment.
You should create a table between User and Cycle

```
class UserCycle
{
    User user
    Cycle cycle
    static hasMany = [roles: Role]
}
```

Role class should look like this:

```
class Role
{
     String roleName
     UserCycle userCycle
}
```

and in code You can refer to that like:

```
UserCycle uc = ...
def roles = uc.roles.list(params) //list of roles
def cycle = uc.cycle
def user = uc.user
```

to add

```
uc.addToRoles(/*Your role*/)
```

to remove

```
uc.removeFromRoles(/*Your role*/)
```

Comment: slight correction in what you have assumed.
User could have many cycles and many roles , 
Cycle can have many users and each user in a particular cycle can have many roles..
hope [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8H2Li.jpg) will help you to understand what i mean.. 

Also the user and Roles table are master tables and they should not belong to any other tables. That is Users and roles should be able to create independently.  
Once a new cycle is created , you should be able to pick an existing employee and an existing role and assign this user-role combination to newly created cycle..

Comment: So if User can have many cycles and cycles can have many users You should create a table between them, for example UserCycle which will include reference to one particulary user and one Role.

Comment: also this links would be helpful:
https://grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML
http://chrisbroadfoot.id.au/2008/07/19/many-to-many-relationship-mapping-with-gorm-grails/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a join table (domain class) that stores the mapping between users and roles in a particular cycle. Here's an example of such a class with some helper methods that may be useful

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role
    Cycle cycle

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, Cycle cycle, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role, cycle: cycle).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Role role, Cycle cycle, boolean flush = false) {
        UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRoleAndCycle(user, role, cycle)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static void removeAll(Cycle cycle) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE cycle=:cycle', [cycle: cycle]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user', 'cycle']
        version false
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `create` method

Comment: Okay. will the removal of a cycle or user cascade deletion on this table?

Comment: No, if you want this you would need to make the relationships bidirectional, and set `User` and `Cycle` as the owners